# How to set Form.Item name of nested object

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

```
const initalValue: any = {

        HIGH: {
          firstRespondedTime: 60000000000,
          everyResponseTime: 60000000000,
          resolutionTime: 300000000000,
        },
 };
```

I want to set Form. Item name of `firstRespondedTime` so how to achieve it on antd

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: to set name in <Form.Item name="HIGH"> that's not i want . I want something like <Form.Item name="HIGH. firstRespondedTime"> so that i can get that value

Comment: @HumanAlien I would appreciate give me feedback that my answer was useful or not

Comment: @saeedShamloo I tried to do so but since I am new i cant give vote.. but thanks man it was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set `Form.Item` name by using an array of strings, like this:

```
<Form name="myForm" initialValues={initalValue}>
   <Form.Item name={['HIGH', 'firstRespondedTime']}>
      <Input placeholder="Please input" />
   </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: What would be the name then?
For example if I want to use the form.setFieldsValue() method, what would be the name to use to reference this Form.Item name={['HIGH', 'firstRespondedTime']}

Comment: You can pass object to setFieldsValue.  For example: form.setFieldsValue({"myForm": {"firstRespondedTime": "New Value" } })